# ng-click is having lag issue in iOS mobiles

Tags: html, css, angularjs, cordova

I have created one numeric keypad from 0 to 9 using `ng-click`. i am using this `generatepin()` function "`ng-click="generatepin('1')`".

The same keypad is working fine with android but it is lagging in **iOS** devices.
I have tried ngTouch and other methods also but lagging issue is still there in **iOS** devices.

Edit for code:

```
$scope.generatepin = function(value, $timeout) {
  console.log(value);
  $scope.pin = $scope.pin + value;
  console.log($scope.pin);
  $scope.count++;
  if ($scope.count == 4) {
    $rootScope.Userpin = $scope.pin;
    $location.path('/confirmPin');
  }
};
```

Comment: What does `generatePin` do? Post some code.

Comment: i am using generatepin to create 4 digit pin when user clicks on any number from 0 to 9 it will bind that number with $scope,pin when count is 4 user gets navigated another page. Below is the code.
  $scope.generatepin=function(value,$timeout)
            {
                 console.log(value);
                 $scope.pin= $scope.pin + value; 
                 console.log($scope.pin);
                 $scope.count++;
                 if($scope.count==4){ $rootScope.Userpin=$scope.pin;
                             $location.path('/confirmPin');}};

Comment: Sounds great, edit your post to show your code.  A quick search shows *many* posts about this, perhaps it's of help: https://www.google.com/?q=ios+click+lag

Comment: Based on that, I don't see anything that would add lag.  Try searching for "ios click lag" and you'll see an abundance of posts about a 300ms delay.

Comment: yes i have seen that but i am not getting how to resolve that 300ms delay.